# Incrementing the result of Map.get()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I get the following error when trying to increment a value obtained from a map in the console in Chrome (50.0.2661.86):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation(…)
```

And similar in Node (4.4.3):

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation
    at repl:1:3
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:262:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:431:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:827:14)
```

The offending code is:

```
var m = new Map()
m.set(1, 0)
m.get(1)
var n = m.get(1)++ // Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation(…)
```

The following also fail:

```
var n = ++m.get(1)
var n = ++(m.get(1))
```

A bug in V8 maybe? Or a misunderstanding in what's happening syntax-wise with the `++` operator?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584369/javascript-map-increment-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert in JS evaluation scheme, but here's my try at explaining that.

In JS, `(1)++` is invalid; you can't change *a value*. What you can do is change a value *attribution* to a name:

```
var a = 1;
a++;
```

In this case the value of `1` doesn't change; what changes is that `a` now points to a different value.

Similarly, you can't increment a value returned by `.get()`; you need to convert it to a named expression before you can change *that*.

In C++ terms we would say that `++` needs an *lvalue*, but the function return is an *rvalue*.

Comment: I should have tried this: `function x() { return 1 }; x()++;` - Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign a value to a function call. That would be like saying

```
m.get(1) = m.get(1) + 1
```

You need to split this into two statements:

```
const n = m.get(1) + 1;
m.set(1, n);
```

Or:

```
const n = m.get(1);
m.set(1, n++);
```

Comment: Even with `var n = (m.get(1))++`?

Comment: As @BartekBanachewicz said. I want the value to be assigned to another variable and bump it by one. I guess the real question is, is this a bug I'm encountering?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz That isn't really relevant. Map of course returns a reference, but a function call cannot be used as the left-hand of an expression. It's not a bug it's the way the language works

Comment: @AdrianLynch In that case, why not `var n = m.get(1) + 1`?