# JavaScript - Map() increment value

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I have a map as follows:

```
let map = new Map();
map.set("a", 1);
//Map is now {'a' => 1}
```

I want to change the value of `a` to 2, or increment it: `map.get("a")++;`

Currently,  I am using the following:

```
map.set("a", (map.get("a"))+1);
```

However, this does not feel right. Does anyone know a cleaner way of doing this? Is it possible?

Comment: Apart from superfluous parens, this is how it's done.

Comment: It's looks okay. PS: it feels you're using `iterate` term while trying to express something else.

Comment: This is okay as JavaScript uses a single-threaded runloop, so there's no chance of `a` getting read within another event handler between the `.get` and `.set` (if this code were in an event handler using a shared map).

Answer (score 33):

The way you do it is fine. That is how you need to do it if you are working with primitive values. If you want to avoid the call to `map.set`, then you must revert to a *reference* to a value. In other words, then you need to store an object, not a primitive:

```
let map = new Map();
map.set("a", {val: 1});
```

And then incrementing becomes:

```
map.get("a").val++;
```

Answer (score 26):

for modern js, you could do this:

```js
map.set("a", (map.get("a") ?? 0) + 1)
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification states, Map manipulation is based `prototypes` and the `prototype` methods assigned to add or retrieve data to or from a Map are the `set` and `get` methods respectively.

Except for the unnecessary parenthesis around your `map.get("a")`, your code is perfectly okay. That's how the Map is meant to be used. If you are looking for something that "may" reduce the length of your code and if it does works for your specific requirement, you may use the JavaScript `Object`.

So dear, your code is just the same as this:

```
map.set("a", map.get("a")+1);
```

Answer (score 7):

Map does not have a built-in feature that increments a value. However, since JavaScript constructs can be modified you can actually do that yourself:

```js
let map = new Map()
// Modify your map
map.constructor.prototype.increment = function (key) {
  this.has(key) && this.set(key, this.get(key) + 1)
}
map.constructor.prototype.decrement = function (key) {
  this.has(key) && this.set(key, this.get(key) - 1)
}

// Now you can use it right away
map.set('test', 1)
map.increment('test')
map.increment('test')
map.decrement('test')
console.log(map.get('test')) // returns 2
```

To make this easier in the future, you can abstract it into a utility:

```js
class CyborgMap extends Map {
  constructor() {
    super()
    
    this.constructor.prototype.increment = function (key) {
      this.has(key) && this.set(key, this.get(key) + 1)
    }
    this.constructor.prototype.decrement = function (key) {
      this.has(key) && this.set(key, this.get(key) - 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Now import it and use it:

```js
import { CyborgMap } from "./utils"

let map = new CyborgMap()
map.set('test', 1)
map.increment('test')
map.increment('test')
map.decrement('test')
console.log(map.get('test')) // returns 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In `map`, if you didn't find any element it will give `undefined`. So, we can do the increment with the below code:

```js
map.set("a", map.get("a") == undefined ? 1 : map.get("a") + 1);
```

or just

```js
map.set('a', map.get('a') + 1 || 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Map#get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) returns the value of the specified element. It is opposite of an object accessor (`object['a']`) and is not eligible for a left-hand side assignment.

The conclusion is to use always [`Map#set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) for setting a new value.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know any cleaner way to do that, nevertheless I think that everything depends from the context of your code.

If you are iterating an array or something else and you want to increase your variable, I suggest to use a local variable to do that and, at the end of the iteration, set the value in the map.

```
var i = map.get('a')

values.forEach( el => {
  i += el.someField
})

map.set('a', i)
```