# Is there any advantage to using Object.create(null) over a Map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, javascript-objects, es6-map

I've seen people use code that looks like

```js
const STUFF_MAP = Object.create(null);
```

`STUFF_MAP` would like suggested only be used like a map, so I understand why using `Object.create(null)` is better than `{}` (removing the properties that could cause conflicts etc.), but is there any advantage to not just use

```js
const STUFF_MAP = new Map();
```

When would I use each one? Does it have to do with being compiled to pre es6?

Comment: I think that code probably predates the `Map` type.

Comment: There's very little reason to use `Object.create(null)`, just use `{}`

Comment: Should I update to use a map? Also would doing so make it worse after compiling to older js?

Comment: Maps are more flexible about what you can use as the keys, but otherwise they're not much different from using ordinary objects.

Comment: But you access them in different ways, so they're not interchangeable.

Comment: Any performance benefit to a map if the keys are just strings anyway?

Comment: I doubt it, but you'd have to benchmark it.

Comment: "*Any performance benefit to a map if the keys are just strings anyway?*" [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @Barmar No, don't use `{}`, which inherits all kinds of unwanted stuff from `Object.prototype` and is not suitable as a map.

Comment: @Bergi There are only a handful of properties in `Object.prototype` -- in ES6 they wised up and defined new methods in `Object` itself (e.g. `Object.entries()`).

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but those are properties that you don't want as keys in your collection.

Comment: @Bergi The chance that you'll have them as actual keys is negligible. But that's also the reason to use `hasOwnProperty()` in situations where it's a possibility. Have you ever heard of an application that failed because of this conflict?

Comment: @Barmar It's not just chance, you also need to consider malicious actors, who pass keys such as `__proto__` on  purpose. There have been quite some vulnerabilities caused by [prototype pollution](https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/prototype-pollution-the-dangerous-and-underrated-vulnerability-impacting-javascript-applications) - see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57960770/1048572) or [there](https://book.hacktricks.xyz/pentesting-web/deserialization/nodejs-proto-prototype-pollution). Even `hasOwnProperty` [needs to be used correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12017693/1048572).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it have to do with being compiled to pre es6?

Yes, `Object.create(null)` is ES5 and won't need a polyfill for `Map`, if you need to support old browsers.

Apart from that, you should prefer the more modern `Map` which is also clearly indicates the purpose of a variable. You will need to access the collection using `has`/`get`/`set` methods, not `in` operator/bracket syntax/assignment. This can sometimes lead to code that isn't as concise, e.g. for [incrementing a value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53584369/1048572) you cannot use a compound assignment operator.

As for performance, there should not be much of a difference; if you care, do a benchmark for your particular situation.